# como hacer una consulta para mostrar el promedio de el dia anterior con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una consulta la cual me muestra el promedio del dia anterior de una columna:

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $estacion=2;
    $sql="SELECT AVG(TS) as TSprom
    FROM sensores 
    WHERE date<'$date' ";
```

hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando pongo el id como condición, me muestra otro valor de otros días, no de el día anterior al actual.

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $estacion=2;
    $sql="SELECT AVG(TS) as TSprom1
    FROM sensores 
    WHERE date<'$date' AND idestacion='$estacion' ";
```

ojala me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: La consulta está bien escrita, le recomiendo intentar lo siguiente: **1.** Copiar el error y mostrarlo, para saber ¿qué pueda estar pasando?. si no hay error y la consulta retorna vacía, entonce saltar este paso. **2.** intentar la consulta con otro valor diferente de `idestacion`, y comentar que sucede. **3.** Revisar bien el nombre de las columnas `idestacion` y `date` que estén bien digitadas. **4.** Si la consulta le funciona sin el `idestacion` entonces puede filtrar la información después del resultado.

Comment: si el Id es int o algún valor numérico en tu tabla, entonces no tiene que llevar comillas, intenta sin comillas y comentas que pasa

Comment: Creo que tendrias que usar un group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso estas colocando en la condicion de la fecha que sea menor a la fecha actual, por lo que te trae el promedio de todos los dias menores a la fecha actual. Deberias cambiar la consulta para que la fecha sea igual a la fecha del dia anterior, directo en Mysql puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT AVG(TS) as TSprom1
    FROM sensores 
    WHERE date = date(date(now())-1) AND idestacion='$estacion'";
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: gracias Kerepakupai eso era, ahora ya puedo ver el promedio de el dia anterior.

Comment: Luis Felipe Castro que bueno que te sirvió. La puedes marcar como resuelta. Saludos